# elements moving out of place on browser re-size, nothing helping

Tags: html, css, browser, resize

On my browser (chrome), maximized,  it looks exactly as i want it to. As soon as I re-size my browser (even just a little bit), the navigation and logo move out of place, overlap/stack on top of each other...I've researched for a few days now and tried a bunch of different things including positioning all elements with %, and assigning a min-width to the container div and **nothing** is helping. I'm obviously missing something. pleeeeeeeease help, i'm going cray! p.s. the logo is positioned to sit between the left & right nav.

```
<body>
<div id="index_container">

<a href="#"><img id="logo" alt="Logo" title="Home" src="#"/></a>

<div id="top_wrap">
    <nav class="left">
        <a href="#" title="About" alt="About Us">about Us</a>
        <a href="#" title="Menu" alt="Menu">menu</a>
    </nav>


    <nav class="right">
        <a href="#" title="Catering" alt="Catering">catering</a>
        <a href="#" title="Find Us" alt="Find Us">find us</a>
    </nav>
</div>
</body>
```

And my CSS, as it sits currently:

```
 #index_container{
 min-width:980px; /* !?!?!??!?!?!?!?!??!?!?!??!?!*/

 }

 #top_wrap{
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 height: 20%;
 width: 100%;
 background: #333;
 opacity: 0.8;

 }

 .left{
 position: absolute;
 left: 18%;
 top: 50%;

  }

.left a{
color:white;
font-size: 28px;
text-decoration: none;
font-family: 'Gafata', sans-serif;
padding: 36px;
}

.right{
position: absolute;
left: 56%;
top:50%;

 }

.right a{
color:white;
font-size: 30px;
text-decoration: none;
font-family: Gafata, sans-serif;
padding: 36px;
font-weight: 400;
 }

.right a:hover{
color: #333;
background-color: white;

 }

.left a:hover{
color: #333;
background-color: white;

}

#logo{
position: absolute;
left:37%;
top:-9%;
height: 310px;
width: 320px;
z-index: 1;
}
```

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/ZaEG2/

Comment: By the way, <nav> will not work in IE8 or earlier - http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_nav.asp

Comment: That’s what you get when you are trying to “nail” everything in place using `position:absolute` for each and every element. Go do some research on how to create a fluid layout without over-using absolute positioning.

Comment: thanks for sending me in the right direction. I've read some more articles and currently playing around with the design and it seems to be working- just need to master relative positioning (and natural flow) the way i did (or didn't) absolute. I just started teaching myself this stuff about a month ago and I knew it couldn't be thhhhat easy lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're using Positon:Absolute for absolutely everything, when you adjust your browser size, you're gonna find it starts dancing all over the page, just use simple height and width elements at 100% to make it more flexible.